# Session.Update en Hibernate no actualiza un registro de tipo Date

Tags: java, hibernate

Buenas,

tengo una aplicación escrita en Java y por detrás una base de datos de Oracle. El mapeo está hecho con Hibernate.

El caso es que tengo un problema cuando intento hacer un update sobre una tabla con contiene una columna de tipo Date.

Tengo una clase llamada `Primerascitas` que tiene un atributo de tipo Date y uno de sus registros tiene un valor de `23/05/2017 11:30`. Yo lo que quiero es actualizar ese registro y cambiarle únicamente la hora para establecerla a las 09:30. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
Session sesion = = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
tx = sesion.beginTransaction();

Primerascitas p = new Primerascitas();
p = (Primerascitas) sesion.get(Primerascitas.class,id.get(0));

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
String fecha = "23/05/2017 09:30";
p.setFecha(sdf.parse(fecha));
sesion.update(p);
tx.commit();
sesion.close();
```

Este código no lanza ninguna excepción ni falla pero no actualiza el registro en la base de datos. Sin embargo, si además de la hora cambio también de fecha, de este modo:

```
String fecha = "24/05/2017 09:30";
p.setFecha(sdf.parse(fecha));
```

El registro le actualiza correctamente en la base de datos. Supongo entonces que en el primer caso no detecta que el registro haya cambiado.

La clase de java que quiero actualizar con el atributo de tipo Date es esta:

```
public class Primerascitas  implements java.io.Serializable {


private int PIdprimeracita;
private Pacientespotenciales pacientespotenciales;
private Date fecha;
private String observaciones;
```

y este es el fichero de mapeo que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quitale el atributo `length` a la propiedad fecha en el fichero de mapeo.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba usando `session.save(p)` ya que el método `save()` Guarda si es nuevo, o actualiza si ya existe.

Answer (score -1):

Esta respuesta llega casi 2 años tarde xD, acabo de tener este mismo problema y por eso llegué aquí, pero he conseguido solucionar el error, así que escribo aquí la solución por si alguien más tiene este error en el futuro:

Yo he quitado la propiedad length del fichero de mapeo y he cambiado el tipo de DATE a TIMESTAMP en la base de datos y en el archivo de mapeo también. He dejado las variables de las clases de tipo date y funciona.
Lo he hecho para añadir, es decir .save, pero para modificar/actualizar también vale.

Un saludo!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!!! solo como referencia, podrias hacer el [tour]?